# Returning JSON Value in Postcodes.io

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to return the value `admin_district` from a string from postcodes.io, but my JS skills are a basic.

It was relatively simple to get the full string using `stringify`, but when I try to extract a value I'm getting stuck. I know I don't need to `parse` the data is already a JSON string, but I don't know how to go about getting the `results` string for validation and the `admin_district`.

EDIT: forgot to add I'm trying to get the `admin_district` into the input

Any help would be appreciated!

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ecm6bfpL/5/)

My Code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#get_postcode").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var fullResult = $("#full_result").hide();
            var postcode = $("#postcode_input").val();
            $.get(encodeURI("https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/" + postcode))
            .done(function (data) {
                fullResult.html(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)).show();
                $("#admin_district").val(data[0].admin_district);
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                fullResult.html(JSON.stringify(error.responseJSON, null, 4)).slideDown();
            });
            });
        });


    </script>
</head>

<body>
     <h4>Get Admin District</h4>
     <input value="TW6 2AP" id="postcode_input">
     <a href="#" id="get_postcode">Request</a>
     <div id="full_result"></div>
    <input id="admin_district" placeholder="Admin District">
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the JSON response, `admin_district` is inside `data.result`, not `data[0]`
you have done it wrong in this line of code `$("#admin_district").val(data[0].admin_district);`, it not like this, change it to `$("#admin_district").val(data.result['admin_district']);`

[Check the js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5u87z23/)

Comment: Ah man that makes sense I did try data["admin_district"], but I was missing the .result - Thank you very much

Comment: @JosephGregory, you owe me one like to the answer buddy... :D .. always happy helping..

Comment: Done, you answered so quickly it made me wait :)